# Can we Export WIT BUG rename it and Import again on the same project

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

We have TFS 2010 environment, We have WIT BUG with so many customizations done. current need is want a new Work Item Type which has exactly same behaviour and functionality as “Bug”, but just a different name (Both Work Items, BUG and new WIT should be in the same team project). So can we Export WIT 'BUG' Rename it and import it to the same Team Project if we do this what are the impacts. Or what else we need to do and where we need to do changes. If not possible please let me know what is the best possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can do this, with no adverse consequences.

If you are using a Developer Command Prompt, the steps are:

1. Run: `witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection /p:YourProject /t:Bug /f:bug.xml`
2. Open `bug.xml`, change the `name` element to something else at the top of the file. Save the file.
3. Run: `witadmin importwitd /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/YourCollection /p:YourProject /f:bug.xml`